# Calculating surface normals for an OpenGL program

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, opengl, optimization

I am basically creating a simple 3D terrain in OpenGL using c++.

The task is calculating face normals by calculating the normals of the vertices which surround each face.

There are 2 methods of implementing this, and I am not sure which one would be the right way, in terms of speed.

Option 1: Have a method calculating the vertex normals, which would end up being an O(n^2) operation.
I would be iterating through a 2D array, to grab each point and performing the calculation. Then store it so it can be retrieved in the next operation.
Then, I would have a method calculating the surface normals, which would end up being an O((n-1)^2) operation, since I would be iterating through a 2D array to grab the vertex normals and then averaging it out.

Advantages I see: I can reduce vertex normal calculations by half. 
Disadvantages: Need to have 2 methods, each iterating over 2D arrays. I also have to keep accessing a 2D array.

Option 2: Have one method calculating surface normals, which would take a face, grab the surrounding points to compute the vertex normals, then compute the surface normal and store it in an array.

Advantages: Here I only have to iterate through a 2D array once, but I would have to repeat vertex normal calculations.
Disadvantages: I would be repeating calculations for vertex normals. For each face I need to do 4 vertex calculations.
What would be the better approach here guys?

Comment: You should not worry so much about time complexity here, because that is an operation you do not want to do every frame anyways.

Comment: store the resulting normals per vertex and keep it as long as the model lives and pass it to the GPU as an attribute